# Using a STM upsd3200 series mcu for the first time

Tags: c++, hardware, microcontroller

I've received a dk 3200 kit recently. I know it's old but I would like to start using it to have more of a challenge than just arduino. It came with the board, an st flashlink FL-101B and some cables. I do not have the install disc, but I found the software for psd soft express online. It doesn't work with current windows 7 64bit. If I could use my arduino to program it, that would be great! Or maybe just do it through USB or the parallel ports? I've read that st provides a stm32 library used to help make code. If that works for my mcu, I'll use that.
Thanks

Comment: That looks to be some sort of 8051 related device (8032 apparently) so you could probably build code with SDCC, but installing it may be a pain.  With the "Discovery" boards for ST's more recent STM8 and STM32 parts selling in the $10-20 range you should only pursue this if you really really want to use that legacy part.

Comment: @ChrisStratton As using a discovery would be nice, I'm kinda stuck with old stuff for now, so I'll have to use the one I have. Thanks though. Also, how would I physically download my code onto it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ST is a company that loves to re-organize their website and break links, but a data sheet for a part of what seems to be the same family as on your board is available from a toolchain vendor at:

http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/st/upsd321x_ds.pdf

On page 118 this seems to indicate that programs can be loaded using JTAG In System Configuration commands, which may be somewhat standardized though quick searching isn't producing a lot of leads.  A reference is also made to ST's AN1153 which would be worth trying to locate a copy of, however it's not entirely clear if that will say anything about the programming, or if it only covers the additional two optional signals which have been added for hardware acceleration of the interface.

In theory, if you can find sufficient information about this device (looking at related devices may provide clues) then you should be able to craft a programming from an Arduino or anything else that can be adapted to twiddle bits at the appropriate voltage/threshold levels.

In practice, you may be better off trying to find an old Windows XP box, or even trying to run that software on a virtual/emulated environment and trap the I/O access either to proxy or to figure out what it is doing and reverse engineer your own programmer.

But unless you have a large installed base of boards using these chips, or particular need some unusual feature of them (I thought I saw something about a built-in CPLD?) it's really not going to be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Chris. I managed to turn it on and it had a sample program on it. I also got a Windows XP and put the latest PSDsoft Express on it. I have no idea how to use it but I managed to erase my board so I know at least the FlashLink is working. When I use the Keil uVision, it doesnt support Flash Link, only ULink. I'm stuck... Could you help me please? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but if you can't afford $10 for a modern eval board, you definitely can't afford my help doing archaeology on an obsolete one.

Comment: Haha thats cool, thanks for your help though, I'm using any parts I can salvage for my Arduino.